# How to use watir-webdriver to find element by class and text

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="test1 test3">1</td>
<td class="test1 test2 test3">1</td>
<td class="test1 test2 test3">2</td>
<td class="test4 test3">2</td>
<td class="test1 test3">2</td>
<td class="test1 test3">3</td>
<td class="test1 test2 test3">3</td>
```

I am trying to find the following `<td>`:

```
<td class="test1">2</td>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
b.td(:class => /(?!.*\btest2\b)/, :text => "2").click
b.td(:class => /^(?!.*\btest2\b)/, :text => "2").click
b.td(:class => /^(?!test2)/, :text => "2").click
b.td(:class => "test1", :class => /(?!test2)/, :text => "2").click
```

All of them return the wrong cell.

Edit:
The number of elements could be different. The order could be different as well.
Pretty much I need to find the element where class is `test1` and class is not `test2` and text is `2`.

Edit2:
I added more classes since it is not restricted to one or two classes. Could be more.

Edit3:
Order of classes could be different:

```
<td class="test2 test1 test3">2</td>
```

Edit4: TD must have test1, must not have test2 and must have text 2

Comment: `b.td(:class => /^test1$/, :text => "2").click`

Comment: When asking, please don't use salutations like "hi", valedictions like "thanks" or "please help", or signatures. Stack Overflow isn't a BBS or discussion forum, we're creating a reference book; Requests for help are not necessary -- create a good question and you'll get help because that's what we're here for. It might not be received as quickly as you'd like but your urgency isn't ours. Read http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html as it's full of good information.

Comment: @the Tin Man I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa I have updated the question. There are could be more than one class and the order could be different as well. Thank you.

Comment: So what makes this cell unique? That it specifically doesn't have class test2?

Comment: Exactly: test1 and not test2 and text 2

Comment: But the one you want will always be exactly `<td class="test1">2</td>`? I.e., `<td class="test1 test3">2</td>` would not ever be what you want, correct?

Comment: I have updated the question: the TD must have class  test1, must not have class test2 and must have text 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the updates, if you're looking for the cell with test 2 and without class test2, you should use this regex on the class:

```
b.td(:class => /^((?!test2).)*$/, :text => "2").click
```

UPDATE:

To require matching test1 but omitting test2, I updated the regex:

```
b.td(:class => /^((?!test2).)*test1((?!test2).)*$/, :text => "2").click
```

Comment: Dane, I have updated the question. It could be more than one class for each element. Thank you.

Comment: Dane, this looks good. It does what needs to do for this particular case. But it will fail in this case: <td class="test4 test3">2</td> since it does not specify test1

Comment: So then it must have test 2, must have class "test1" and must omit class "test2"? You should update the question to specify that.

Comment: This does the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the case of `<td class="test1 test4">2</td>` appearing on the page before `<td class="test1">2</td>`. It will click the `td` with class `test1 test4` and not the `td` with class exactly equal to `test1`. But it is difficult to know for sure what @Andrey was asking for.

Comment: @pjd At your scenario the TDs are not unique by definition. The both have class test1, both do not have class test2 and both have text 2. This will never happen in my case.

Comment: I see. That was unclear to me. I have amended my own answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.td(:class => "test1", :text => "2").click
```

should do the trick.

I tested this, but for some reason without the containing `<table>` tag, watir wasn't recognizing the html for the `<td>` elements. So after adding that, this worked.

Comment: For me at least, this seems to click the first `td` with text `2` (i.e, `<td class="test1 test2">2</td>`), which is not the one needed.

Comment: This does not do the job. It does click the wrong element. Thank you.

Comment: You should share more html. There's clearly more to this story than you're showing. Where is the `a` tag anyway? This is a javascript link? You're not showing any of that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding regex when possible, the implementation of it is very slow. This is more readable and flexible, and probably makes fewer wire calls (i.e. faster):

```
elements = b.tds(class: 'test1', text: '2')
element = elements.find { |td| !td.attribute_value('class').include?('text2') }
element.click
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
td_array=b.tds.to_a
td_array.each do |td|
  if td.class_name =~ /test1/ && td.class_name !~ /test2/ && td.text == '2'
    b.td(:index, td_array.index(td)).click
  end
end
```

This will click every `td` on the page with class containing `test1` and not containing `test2` and with text equal to `2`. As you mentioned in a comment to Dane Andersen's answer, there should never be more than 1 such `td` to click.